# How can I avoid overwriting the default signature with a pasted image?

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

My default email signature is overwritten by an embedded image. The signature shows up at first and then the picture takes its place.

I want this code to work for other people. How can I add the default email signature?

```vb
Sub Send_Email()

    Dim pdfPath As String, pdfName As String

    ' PDF name same as the workbook.name
    pdfName = "VW Fuel Marks_" & Format(Date, "m.d.yyyy")

    ' PDF save path same as workbook path, where the workbook is saved
    pdfPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & pdfName & ".pdf"

    ' Selecting sheets (if any of the sheets hidden it will run to an error)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Daily Dashboard-Page1", "Daily Dashboard-Page2", "Daily Dashboard-Page3", "Daily Dashboard-Page4")).Select

    ' Create PDF document and open it (if a pdf with a same
    ' name is already opened it will run to an error)
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfPath, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
      IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    Application.Worksheets(19).Range("A1:T42").CopyPicture xlScreen, xlPicture

    Dim OApp As Object, OMail As Object, Signature As String
    Dim cell As Range, S As String, WMBody As String, lFile As Long

    Set OApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OMail = OApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OMail
        .Display
    End With

    Signature = OMail.HTMLBody

    With OMail
        .To = Range("AG3").Value
        .CC = Range("AG4").Value
        .Subject = Range("A1").Value
        .HTMLBody = Replace(Signature, "<div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>", "<div class=WordSection1><p class=MsoNormal><o:p>" & sBody)
        .Attachments.Add pdfPath
        OMail.Display
    End With

    '.Attachments.Add
    Set ins = OMail.GetInspector

    ' We need to add a reference to the Microsoft Word Object Library
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Set doc = ins.WordEditor
    doc.Select
    doc.Application.Selection.Paste
    OMail.Display

    Set OMail = Nothing
    Set OApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `display` before `htmlbody` and don't display it again.

Comment: what is `sBody`? looks like you are overriding the email body, try using [Option Explicit statement] [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/option-explicit-statement]

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the content right after the opening `<body>` tag. In that case the rest content will be preserved as is.

```
With OMail
    .Display
End With

Signature = OMail.HTMLBody

With OMail
    .To = Range("AG3").Value
    .CC = Range("AG4").Value
    .Subject = Range("A1").Value

     ' here you need to find the <body> tag and insert the new content right after it
    .HTMLBody = ...

    .Attachments.Add pdfPath
    OMail.Display
End With
```

You can use [VBA string functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) to find the `<body>` tag and paste the content right after it.

Answer (score 0):

You select the body then paste over it.

```vb
Set doc = ins.WordEditor
doc.Select
doc.Application.Selection.Paste
```

Instead paste at the top, in a smaller size.

```vb
Set doc = ins.WordEditor
doc.Range(0, 0).Paste
```

This pastes at the top with size matching your code.

```vb
Set doc = ins.WordEditor
Dim wdRange As Word.Range
Set wdRange = doc.Range(0, 0)
wdRange.Select
doc.Application.Selection.Paste
```

Comment: Hi! This worked for me. Only thing is that the picture that gets inserted into the email is now really small. I can manually increase the size of the image before sending the email out but do you think there is a way for the picture to be of good size automatically?